# Sending PDF to backend breaks encoding and characters

Tags: javascript, java, jax-rs

I try to use axios to send PDF generated in frontend, to be saved in backend.

I cant seem to get all the types straight..

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/pdfs`,
        data,
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            }
        })
```

Java back:

```
@POST
@Path("/pdfs")
public void test(final File req,
                 final @Context SecurityContext securityContext) throws IOException, SQLException {

    pdfService.init(req);

}
```

So very simple stuff.
PDF is fine otherways but characters like ö and ä are broken and even some spaces are printed as "Â "

This seems to happen as pdf is send and on way to backend, since other button which simply downloads same PDF from frontend (no connection to backend) is 100% fine.

Should i maybe use responseType: Blob, or maybe try to adjust java side?

When printed in console the data at backend side when arriving seem like this (still containing all the special characters):

```
%PDF-1.3
%ºß¬à
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
.....
```

But if i stop the running with debugger, before pdfService and take a look at tmp/ files, it's already messed up..

Comment: Please, add the code of your PdfService class

Comment: Please, as said its destroyed before ever entering pdfService so i doubt that really matters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah,

You need to encode file with base64, then send
and then decode back again when received file is received. Only way i found it to work.